# Why I can't install packages with npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Trying simple command npm i --legacy-peer-deps and this is what i get:

[image]

```
1474 verbose type system
1475 verbose stack FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch     https://registry.npmjs.org/@nrwl%2freact: 12620:error:1408F119:SSL     routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record     mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
1475 verbose stack
1475 verbose stack     at     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:168:15
1475 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
1475 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument     (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:99:25)
1475 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest     (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:124:23)
1475 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge]     (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\bui    ld-ideal-tree.js:1107:19)
1475 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep]     (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\bui    ld-ideal-tree.js:976:11)
1475 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree     (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\bui    ld-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
1475 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
1475 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:154:5)
1475 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:145:5)
1476 verbose cwd D:\Samir\Projects\GO\gomango-next
1477 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
1478 verbose node v14.19.3
1479 verbose npm  v8.16.0
1480 error code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
1481 error errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
1482 error Invalid response body while trying to fetch     https://registry.npmjs.org/@nrwl%2freact: 12620:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
1482 error
1483 verbose exit 1
1484 timing npm Completed in 33810ms
1485 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1660050096991
1486 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1660050097001
1487 verbose code 1
1488 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
1488 error     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-09T13_01_36_761Z-debug-0.log
```

node version: 14.19.3

npm version: 8.16.0

OS: Windows

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am running "npm install" and getting this error on the screenshot everytime
Please let me know, what additional info I can provide